# Building OpenCV from source in VS2012

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

As it turns out that the default build I downloaded from `opencv.org` does NOT contain the CUDA libraries, I am trying to build it manually from source.

I used `CMake` to create a solution for Visual C++ 11 (Visual Studio 2012), then I opened the `OpenCV.sln` project.

Then, I selected the `ALL_BUILD` item from the Solution Explorer, and clicked on `Build`.

I always get such errors (a very partial list, there are much more like these):

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_imgproc249d.lib'
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_nonfree249d.lib'
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_objdetect249d.lib'
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ml249d.lib'
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_contrib249d.lib'
```

I guess they should not anyway exist, as these files should be built by this process, so why would it anyway look for them? Or does it fail to open them for writing?

Can you please help me?

Comment: Some libraries need to link other opencv libs.  Have you checked imgproc a.s.o. have been build. I would suggest you to build one after another beginning with the opencv_core,by clicking with the right mousebottom on the project and than select build.

Comment: I gave it up.. Finally just moved to `OpenCV 3.0.0` - It contained what I needed working (HOGDescriptor)